# R: Care: how to predict new case with a subset of predictors?

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a situation that the features/predictors are generated by dcast. therefore, some columns will be missing for the new cases in real production.

For example:

> ```
> # caret 
> # load libraries 
> require("caret")
> require("mlbench") 
> data(BostonHousing) 
> # train 
> set.seed(7) 
> control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5) 
> fit.lm <- train(medv~., data=BostonHousing, method="lm",     metric="RMSE", preProc=c("center", "scale"), trControl=control)
> ```

For the prediction, the missing column case can be simulated as

> ```
> require(dpllyr) 
> newcases <- BostonHousing[1:3,] %>% select(-chas)
> ```

However, this leads to a prediction error:

> ```
>  predict(fit.lm,newcases)
>  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'chas' not found
> ```

Comment: one way I can think of is to fill the missing column with rbind. e.g., `new %>% bind_rows(BostonHousing[1,])`

Comment: you can also assign the column to be `NA`.

Comment: @akash87, do you know how to automate this? for example, you don't know "chas" is missing at prediction time.

Comment: I think you have a fundamental issue here. You may actually need to impute values to run the prediction. But question: why do you keep the variables that are missing after the `dcast` in the original model?